# Invalid procedure call or argument 5 with VBA Right function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting 'Invalid procedure call or argument: 5' error on the following piece of code bolded below. It has run successfully in the past with strings that longer than the one causing the error today. I have tried to include all pertinent information for troubleshooting. I did not write this code so I am lost as to what the issue could be. Any help would be appreciated to resolve the error. Debugger highlights the commented line below.

```vb
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro-Tool").Cells(6, 5) <> "" Then
    testsetfolderpath = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro-Tool").Cells(6, 5)
    'get project name from Test SetFolder Path.
    'cycle_int = InStrRev(testsetfolderpath, "\")
    'test_mode = VBA.Right(testsetfolderpath, Len(testsetfolderpath) - cycle_int)
    'inter_str = VBA.Left(testsetfolderpath, cycle_int - 1)
    'inter_str1 = VBA.Left(inter_str, InStrRev(inter_str, "\") - 1)
    'release_name = VBA.Right(inter_str1, Len(inter_str1) - InStrRev(inter_str1, "\"))
    release_name = "^" + ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro-Tool").Cells(7, 5) + "^"
    
    Set tsetfactory = QcConnection.TestSetFactory
    Set LabFilter = tsetfactory.Filter
    LabFilter.Filter("CY_FOLDER_ID") = "^" + testsetfolderpath + "^"

    Set testsets = LabFilter.NewList
    i = 3
    For Each tset In testsets
        Set tsetfold = tset.TestSetFolder

' Error here ----------------------------------------------

        parse_str = Right(tsetfold.Path, Len(tsetfold.Path) - Len(testsetfolderpath) - 1)

' ---------------------------------------------------------
        pos1 = InStr(1, parse_str, "\")
        If pos1 = 0 Then
            func_area = parse_str
            bus_process = parse_str
            stream = parse_str
        Else
            func_area = Left(parse_str, pos1 - 1)
            bus_process = Right(parse_str, Len(parse_str) - pos1)
            pos2 = InStr(1, bus_process, "\")
            If pos2 = 0 Then
                stream = bus_process
            Else
                stream = Left(bus_process, pos2 - 1)
            End If
        End If
```

Additional information within the code that may be useful for troubleshooting:

```vb
Public field_names, parse_str, testsetfolderpath, inter_str1, test_mode, cycle_folder As String
Public tsetfold As TestSetFolder
```

```
testsetfolderpath = Root\System Test\2021 Projects\XXXX123456 Xxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx XX Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxx X\Xxxxxx X.X_XXX
```

Comment: I was in the process of editing to make it more clear, but could not because another user was editing.  the Line the debugger is highlighting is:  parse_str = Right(tsetfold.Path, Len(tsetfold.Path) - Len(testsetfolderpath) - 1)

Comment: What is the value of `tsetfold.Path`? And the `len` returns in that line. I'm guessing that `Len(testsetfolderpath)` > `Len(tsetfold.Path)` and you can't put a negative into that argument.

Comment: @Warcupine The value of tsetfold.Path & testsetfolder path are equal, resulting in 'Empty' value of **parse_str** .  How do I account for this scenario so the code will complete without error?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do with `Parse_str` but to avoid the error you need to make sure that the second argument in `Right()` is >=0, though you probably don't want a 0 as that will return an empty string. So at the very least change `-1` to `+1`. If the two strings are equal It seems like there is some logical error in what you are trying to accomplish.